# How to pass url in services in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am able to pass parameters to a view but when I try to pass a full link like http://google.com it bugs out. I can pass google.com without any problems.

```
.state('nav.view2', {
    url: '/view2/:url',
    views: {
        'games-tab': {
            templateUrl: 'src/views/view2.html',
            controller: 'view2'
        }
    }
})

.controller('view1', function($scope, $stateParams, $http, $state) {
    $scope.open = function(googleUrl)
    {
        $state.go('nav.view2', {url: googleUrl});
    }
})
```

How do I pass full urls without problem? This is on iconic platform if that is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I found the problem in my code. It was at the bottom that set any none defined state to default to another view. It was happening so fast I didn't see it.